# How to group objects in PostScript?

Tags: grouping, postscript

I'm trying to print a series of shapes and text is ps. I would like to group each single letter with one shape into one object. It is possible to do this in ps?

Thanks!

Comment: We'd like to help, but we need a lot more details about what you're trying to do. Can you add a link to a hand-drawn sketch?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'group' ? There is no concept of grouping in PostScript, but its possible you mean something different to my understanding.

You could define a procedure to draw a series of graphical primitives and refer to that as a 'group'. Or you could define a form, and the form can be considered a 'group'. Or you could define a pattern and paint with that, in a sense that's a group too.

When it comes to text, 'each single letter with one shape' is a reasonable description of a glyph in a specific font. That's already a single object.